# Some javascript is crashing ie7 only how to debug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i am using some plugin and updated jquery recently , some click on plugin crashes IE7 , is there anyway i can debug where exactly it is causing problem and crashing IE7.

i want some pointers to debug where the error is?

I am not getting any clue as the browser is crashing without any error.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

I found the problem , its throwing error at the following location

**removeAttr** is throwing error , if i comment that it works

```
  $('#myImgagesDiv img').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('myCustomattr')) {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('myCustomattr'));
        $(this).removeAttr('myCustomattr'); // code creating problem
    };
});
```